# How to get data from events to the main function?

Tags: java, swing, events

I am currently creating a chess game. This is also my first project where I try to create a gui, so please tell me if there are cleaner ways to write this code. So I used java swing to create 64 buttons that print their coordinates to the console when pressed.

I also managed to create a loop in my main method to run my chess engine using console inputs. My problem is that I dont know how to get the coordinates from my eventListeners to my main loop such that it moves a piece.

I added the main loop and the action performed method. Hope that is enough code to solve my struggle.

Thanks to everyone that takes time to help me!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int[] coordinates = new int[4];
    
    Player player = new Player();
    Board board = new Board();
    Input input = new Input();
    board.showBoard();
    // here I give the gui object the references to my input and board objects 
    // so that it can call their methods and thereby give the information to them   
    Gui gui = new Gui(board, input); 

    
    while(!player.isCheckmate(board)) { 
    
        coordinates = input.getInput(board, player).clone();// get coordinates xpos, ypos, xposnew, yposnew
    
        Piece activePiece = board.getPiece(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]); // get the chosen piece
        
        if(!activePiece.isLegalMove(board, coordinates[2], coordinates[3]))// move the active piece to chosen destination
        {
            System.out.println("No legal move. Try again");
            continue;
        }
        
        activePiece.move(board, coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);
        
        player.switchPlayerTurn();
        
        player.isCheckmate(board);
        board.showBoard();
    }
     
}
```

Here is the actionPerformed method

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String[] numbers = button.getActionCommand().split("");
        
        if(coordinates[2] !=-1)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++)
                coordinates[i] = -1;
        } 
        if(coordinates[0] == -1) {
            coordinates[0] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
            coordinates[1] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
        } else if(coordinates[2] == -1) {
            coordinates[2] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
            coordinates[3] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
            }
        
        System.out.println("x coodinate = " + Integer.toString(coordinates[0]));
        System.out.println("y coodinate = " + Integer.toString(coordinates[1]));
        System.out.println("destination x coodinate = " + Integer.toString(coordinates[2]));
        System.out.println("destination y coodinate = " + Integer.toString(coordinates[3]));
        
    }
```

Comment: Can I suggest you to not use buttons? I think it would be easier for you to create a custom class `Piece` that will be extended from the other pieces. Furthermore, you could simply setup an action listener and handle the click/drag in the mother class (`Piece`).

Comment: I already have a a mother class piece so that should be no problem. I initally did it this way to seperate my input from the rest of the game.  How would you set up the a drag and drop functionallity? Some links to read up would be great if you dont have time for an example. as I said this is my first time writing a gui.

Comment: @Dawa [Drag and Drop Tutorial](https://zetcode.com/javaswing/draganddrop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding passing data from your events to the main, you will need to carry a reference to your object managing `Piece` coordinates (I assume this is your `Board` object). You'll want to add something like:

```
class Board {
  //Other class stuff
  
  public void setPiecePosition(Piece targetPiece, Point coordPoint) {
    //Code to update your tracking
  }
}
```

And then add something like this to your event:

```
board.setPiecePosition(targetPiece, new Point(xCoord, yCoord));
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim Hunter both for your solution and the tutorial link. Both are very helpfull!

Comment: @Dawa A recommendation... Think carefully about [dividing responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). What should a `Piece` care about? Is it the `Piece` object's job to manage interactions with other `Piece` objects or is that the `Board` object's job? Does a `Piece` care about where it's positioned or does the `Board` care? Should a `Board` handle coordinates and objects occupying them or should it delegate that to `Tile` objects? No wrong answer to these questions, just something to consider for your overall design approach.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't put much thought into that. I will keep that in mind for my next project. Thanks again!